# @PostFilter with contains?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Here is my entity class:

```
class ModelEntity {
  List<String> list;
  ...
}
```

Now I want to post filter returned objects and return only objects where list contains 'something'. Is that even possible? And if yes, how to do this?
I believe it would have to be sth like this (ofc. with change of 'contains'):

```
@PostFilter("(filterObject.list contains 'something')")
List<ModelEntity> findAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Spring expression engine provides ***"contains"*** as expression as out-of-box solution.

Check [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html) link for Spring security expressions.

But you can define your own custom expression handler for this.

There are many ways for define custom expression handler in Spring.

1. By implementing **PermissionEvaluator**.
2. By implementing **MethodSecurityExpressionOperations**.

For examples and more explanation follow [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression) blog.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply invoke the `contains` method of `java.util.List` using SpEL:

```java
@PostFilter("filterObject.list.contains('something')")
List<ModelEntity> findAll()
```